# "-qt=5 -version returned non-zero exit status" error when installing Wireshark

Tags: linux, qt, wireshark

When I wanted to install Wireshark software from **Source Code** on Debian 8 Linux distro, I saw the following error messages:

```
...
...
checking for uic... /usr/bin/uic
checking for qtchooser... (cached) /usr/bin/qtchooser
checking for moc... /usr/bin/moc
checking for qtchooser... (cached) /usr/bin/qtchooser
checking for rcc... /usr/bin/rcc
checking for qtchooser... (cached) /usr/bin/qtchooser
checking for lrelease... /usr/bin/lrelease
checking whether lrelease -version works... no
configure: error: /usr/bin/lrelease -qt=5 -version returned non-zero exit status
```

It should be noted that the above error message is shown after running the following command:

```
./configure --with-ssl --enable-setcap-install --with-dumpcap-group=wireshark
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to have the `qttools5-dev-tools` package installed in order to build Qt5 applications like Wireshark.